# Customizing tags auto-completion

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Is it possible to tweak auto-completion of tag names to make it seem like if there were multiple levels of tags? For example:

```
* Movie A              :entertainment:movies:action:
* Movie B              :entertainment:movies:horror:
* Album X              :entertainment:music:
* Spatula              :to_buy:cooking:
* Album Y              :to_buy:music:
```

When setting a new tag on an item, if no tags are currently set, by pressing `TAB` I would be presented with two options: "entertainment" and "to_buy" (since they are the only two first-level tags). Suppose I select "entertainment" as the first tag, and that I want to add a second tag. I would press `TAB` again to see the options and I would only be presented with "movies" and "music", since they are the second-level tags of "entertainment".